# send value from views in form of {{ FORM:: }} and recieve value in controller

Tags: laravel-4.2

i want to send value to controller from view, it is coming "null",i was expecting input of search button,

**Views page code:**

```
 {{ Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'searchingDoctors','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])  }}

            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
                <input type="submit" id="search" name="search" value="Serach" class="search" />
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

**route.php code:**

```
Route::post('searchingDoctors/{search}', array('as'=>'searchingDoctors','uses'=>'PublicSearchController@searchingDoctors'));
```

**controller file code:**

```
public function searchingDoctors($search) {

        dd($data = Input::get($search));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following in your controller

```
public function searchingDoctors() {

        $data = Input::get("search");
}
```

Change route from

```
Route::post('searchingDoctors/{search}', array('as'=>'searchingDoctors','uses'=>'PublicSearchController@searchingDoctors'));
```

to

```
Route::post('searchingDoctors, array('as'=>'searchingDoctors','uses'=>'PublicSearchController@searchingDoctors'));
```

**EDIT**

Also change view to following

```
{{ Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'searchingDoctors','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])  }}

            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
                <input type="submit" id="search" name="search-button" value="Serach" class="search" />
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function searchingDoctors() {

        dd($data = Input::get('search'));
}
```

and make sure you imported

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```